# Duplicate key found, but nothing matches in the table

Tags: postgresql

I have a function which receives some parameters, does a `SELECT` to see if a table row exists and returns `FALSE` if so. If not, it does an `INSERT` but currently always fails with a '*duplicate key*'. Here's a pseudo-code version...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bob_function (
    p_work_id               INTEGER,
    p_location_id           VARCHAR,
    p_area_id               VARCHAR,
    p_scheduled_work_no     INTEGER,
    p_start_date_time       TIMESTAMPTZ,
    p_work_date_time        TIMESTAMPTZ,
    p_user_id               INTEGER,
    p_comments              TEXT,
    p_work_stat_code        CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
            FROM work_table
            WHERE location_id         = p_location_id
            AND   area_id             = p_area_id
            AND   work_id             = p_work_id
            AND   scheduled_work_no   = p_scheduled_work_no
            AND   start_date_time     = p_start_date_time
            AND   user_work_id        = p_user_id
            AND   work_date_time      = p_work_date_time
    )
    THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Work already exists - SKIPPING';
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO work_table (
                location_id,
                area_id,
                work_id,
                scheduled_work_no,
                start_date_time,
                user_work_id,
                work_date_time,
                stat_code,
                comment
        )
        VALUES (
                p_location_id,
                p_area_id,
                p_work_id,
                p_scheduled_work_no,
                p_start_date_time,
                p_user_id,
                p_work_date_time,
                v_work_stat_code,
                p_comments
        );
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

The primary key is defined thus...

```
myDb=# \d task_work_pk
                     Index "schema1.task_work_pk"
      Column       |            Type             | Key? |    Definition
-------------------+-----------------------------+------+-------------------
 location_id       | character varying(8)        | yes  | location_id
 area_id           | character varying(3)        | yes  | area_id
 work_id           | integer                     | yes  | work_id
 scheduled_work_no | integer                     | yes  | scheduled_work_no
 start_date_time   | timestamp(0) with time zone | yes  | start_date_time
 user_work_id      | integer                     | yes  | user_work_id      
 work_date_time    | timestamp(0) with time zone | yes  | work_date_time
primary key, btree, for table "schema1.work_table"
```

Currently I get the following error every time I run this function...

```
ERROR:  23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "task_work_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (location_id, area_id, work_id, scheduled_work_no, start_date_time, user_work_id, work_date_time)=(SITE_1, BOB, 218, 5, 2021-07-09 00:28:00+10, 1, 2021-07-09 21:00:15+10) already exists.
```

There are *no rows whatsoever* with `work_id = 218` and this is the only place in the **entire database** where this table is written to. The function is only called no more frequently than once a minute and I'm 99% sure I've not got any race condition.

**EDIT**: updated to remove errors

Comment: Note: **1)** you don't need `IF()`, **2)** you don't need a function, **3)** you don't need `plpgsql`.

Comment: This is an example of a fraction of what's going on in the function. There's loads of other guff before and after, but it's not relevant to this issue so I've left it out

Comment: Note2: putting **all** columns of a *fat* junction table into a UNIQUE constraint (or PK) is ... questionable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ignoring your PLPGSQL code because it is not real code and has obvious flaws.

Given that 218 doesn't exist the only way to cause that error without 218 pre-existing  is to insert the same record twice in a single transaction.

Comment: Could you please explain the "obvious flaws"

Comment: `v_work_schedule_no` is null when you do the select and the insert.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's populated from an earlier query or, if that can't be done, `v_work_schedule_no = p_scheduled_work_no`. So for this pared-down example, `v_work_schedule_no` could be removed

Comment: This is why the instuctions say that code should demostrate the problem not merely resemble it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Help others reproduce the problem"